# Memory Clean Up in Windows Phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How i can implement memory clean up in WP7? Does GC.Collect() do the trick? or need clean up manually?

Comment: In what context? What kind of cleaning up do you need to do? Cleaning up in/after your own application, or some kind of more general clean-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually clean up memory on Windows Phone. You shouldn't call `GC.Collect()` unless it's absolutely necessary.

I would recommend you read this article: [Windows Phone 7 App Development: When does the GC run](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2010/07/29/windows-phone-7-app-development-when-does-the-gc-run.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Claus mentioned, the GC handles memory cleanup for you. If you are asking because you are running into memory usage issues, you can use the profile your memory usage using the [Windows Phone Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202935%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) (as long as you are targetting 7.1).